# Problems with project. Service worker / Images / Task Bars

Tags: javascript, html, css, service-worker, responsiveness

My project uses mainly html,css, javascript and the google api.

I’m having trouble with the images not showing up at my project (maybe there is a problem with the service worker?) and the drop down menus of neighborhoods and cuisines also don’t work.

Pls comment if you find something wrong or have any ideas that will help

Here’s my github repo:https://github.com/MariaMich/mws-restaurant-stage-1

Comment: Please be a little more descriptive about your problem

Comment: I think there is problem with my service worker making the images not show up? const cacheName = "app-static-v1";
const urlsToCache = [
 '/',
  'css/styles.css',
  'data/restaurants.json',
  'img/1.jpg', to img 10 'js/dbhelper.js',
  'js/main.js',
  'js/restaurant_info.js'
];
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
 event.waitUntil(
  caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => cacheaddAll(urlsToCache);
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
 event.respondWith(
  caches.match(event.request).then(response => {
   if (response) {return response;}
   {return fetch(event.request);}

Comment: /Initialising the service worker
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('/mws-restaurant-stage-1/sw.js', {
      scope: './'
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Service Worker initialised scope:', reg.scope);
    })
    .catch() => {
      console.log('An error occured while trying to load the service worker');
    });
}
console.log('An error occured while trying to load the service worker'); This is line shows up on error on Dev Tools (An error occured while trying to load the service worker DOMException: "The operation is insecure.")

Comment: Please put it in your question, not a comment. And please put it in a code block.